# UITextView Scrolling Memory Issue on iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, uitextview, ios7

I have a trouble with UITextView scrolling on iOS7 which didn't happen on iOS6.

When I set text on UITextView and scroll it fast on device, Xcode5 memory report shows it consuming huge memory.  However, when I do the same on simulater, it's just fine.

Does anybody has the same issue?  I use iOS7 and Xcode5.0, and clean installed iPhone5 for device.

**This is the code for the test.**

```
UITextView *textView    = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
NSString *textPath      = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *string        = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:textPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

textView.text = string;
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]; 
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

**Sample Project**
https://github.com/umekun123/iOS7-UITextView-Scrolling--Test

**Profiling Picture**
[image]

Comment: Please consider raising a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Hello, yes, I already submitted a bug report, I just wondered maybe I was missing something.

Comment: I get the same thing. I click into a textfield and it brings up memory by 0.2mb and with every click it does the same. When I click out of the textfield it goes up again and usually says my application is using an incorrect context. It never releases the memory either.